# Php/Mysql Simple survey

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make a little php poll. The script should ask the users a question they can only answer by numbers from 0-999. After pressing the submit button the data should be stored into mysql. So I just want to know how much users choosed the same number (in percent). It's a simple poll but I don't want any output to be shown.

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to do, it might be more useful to group the numbers into ranges such as (0-100), (100-200), etc... instead of counting each number individually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use COUNT and GROUP BY:

```
SELECT
    number,
    COUNT(number) * 100 / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1) AS percent
FROM table1
GROUP BY number
ORDER BY COUNT(number) DESC
```

Results:

```
number  percent
2       50.0000
3       30.0000
1       20.0000
```

Test data:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (number INT NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO table1 (number) VALUES (1),(1),(2),(2),(2),(2),(2),(3),(3),(3);
```

Comment: @Mark it's perfect.
but what happened if number 4 has count zero? i get 4 in resultset with count zero or not?

Comment: @Salil If there's no vote for a particular number it will not appear in the result set.

Comment: is it there any way so that i get default count =0 if no vote is present?

Answer (score 1):

here you go: http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/creating-a-web-poll-with-php--net-14257
It's simple tutorial how to make poll.

YOu can use http://www.phpkobo.com/ajax_poll.php if you need something done..

Comment: Link is broken unfortunately